# No Code Coverage on String assignments (Auth.RegHandler)

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, delegated-authentication

We are working on implementing an Open ID Connect for community authentication. I am having some trouble getting code coverage on the mapping of Strings from my 3rd-party UserInfo provider.

Here are the assignments in the class:

[image: Coverage Results]

And the test class:

```
@isTest
private class TestCredentialsRegistrationHandler {
static testMethod void testCreateAndUpdateUser() {
    CredentialsRegHandler handler = new CredentialsRegHandler();
    Map<String,String> attributeMap = new Map<String, String>();
            attributeMap.put('/schemas/2015/09/identity/claims/salesforceid', '000000000000001');
            attributeMap.put('cCSFID', 'accts.Id');
            attributeMap.put('cEmail' , 'u.Email');
            attributeMap.put('fName', 'u.FirstName');
            attributeMap.put('lName', 'u.LastName');
            attributeMap.put('cCompanyId', 'accts.Id');
            attributeMap.put('cCompanyName', 'accts.Name');
            attributeMap.put('cVendor', 'accts.Vendor_Code__c');


    Auth.UserData sampleData = new Auth.UserData('testId', 'testFirst', 'testLast',
        'testFirst testLast', 'testuser@example.org', null, 'testuserlong@salesforce.com', 'en_US', 'facebook',
        null, attributeMap);

    User u = handler.createUser(null, sampleData);

    insert(u);

    String uid = u.id;
```

Not sure what the best way to test these and get the code coverage I need. Any code help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never put `sfdc_networkid` into your `attributeMap`. All of those lines depend on this key being in the map. Before you call your handler, make sure you add a line like:

```
attributeMap.put('sfdc_networkid', '<some_value>');
```

Note that the `Technical Library` states that **rigorous assertions are the most important part of unit testing**, and they are completely missing from your test method!

> #### [Verify the results are correct](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests#Verify_the_results_are_correct)
>
> Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is the most important part of unit testing. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as [smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests.
>
> A good way to tell if unit tests are properly verifying results is to look for liberal use of the `System.assert()` methods. If there aren’t any `System.assert()` method calls, then the tests aren’t verifying results properly. And, no, `System.assert(true);` doesn’t count.

Make sure you assert on the output of your method to verify the results are correct.

```
attributeMap.put('sfdc_networkid', '<some_value>');
Auth.UserData sampleData = new Auth.UserData(...);

Test.startTest();
    User output = handler.createUser(null, sampleData);
Test.stopTest();

system.assertEquals('u.FirstName', output.FirstName, '<assertion_message_here>');
//assert on other fields
```

Comment: Made the change mentioned above and got an additional 2 lines of coverage on String cCSFID and String cuSFID. Do you know why it's not grabbing them all?

Comment: Also, my assertions were just a little further down the page! ;-) thanks for looking out though.

Comment: Good to know about the assertions. :) Always merits mention. I'm not sure why it wouldn't cover the other lines, sounds like a silently swallowed error, though you don't appear to be catching any exceptions.

Comment: Good call: 13:02:18:000 FATAL_ERROR Class.TestCredentialsRegistrationHandler.testCreateAndUpdateUser: line 19, column 1